# Does Thor lose certain powers without his hammer?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

When Thor loses his hammer, he believes he is no longer as strong as he was because he lost his powers as the God Of Thunder.

Odin comes to him in a vision (twice) and shows that the hammer "was to focus his power". We first see that Thor has the powers of thunder within him when he was being battered by Hulk.

When Hela was about to kill him and asked him "What are you the God of?" Odin came to him and told him he has the powers of the hammer inside him.

If this is the case does he lose certain powers because he no longer has it with him physically?

For example:

At the start of the film Thor is seen placing the hammer on the jaw of the dragon and causing it to be locked down on the ground because as we already know 'those who are worthy can only posses the powers of Thor'.

Thor has been seen before at other times placing the hammer on villains to stop them from moving.

Without his hammer how will he do this? Or does he lose this power?

Another power he had was to control his hammer psychologically, for example when in the Sanctum Sanctorium he calls for the hammer and it travels to him (while smashing a few stuff) and he has the power to stop the velocity of the hammer mid-air for example when fighting Surturs minions  the hammer is seen flying in circles then decelerating and returning to his palm at command.

Comment: http://marvel.com/universe/Thor_complete_powers

Comment: The hammer is a device, not a power.  If someone loses a gun, there was no "fire bullets" power they had that they've now lost.  That said, it was confirmed in the film that his flight was essentially him twirling and throwing his hammer while holding it.  Inability to fly seemed to have been confirmed when he needed Hulk to get him and Valkrie onto the departing ship.

Comment: @sirjonsnow actually i believe he can fly because after hitting Hela with a thunder bolt he flies down to the bridge I think Hulk and Valkyrie carried him because he was injured

Comment: That could be; I almost mentioned he was kind of "floaty" during the final battle, but we never see him zooming around either.

Comment: Well it would be too unrealistic if he was zooming around already in the next movie he probably will like for example Doctor Strange in the first movie was struggling to open a portal but in Thor Ragnarok he was teleporting around the place completely different to the first movie.

Comment: Don't forget that after being told not to Fight, Hulk basically made the decision to carry them without asking. Thor may well have been able to fly on his own but not had the chance as Hulk immediately grabbed him after being told not to fight.

Comment: The premise of your question defeats itself. If Thor has a power (= innate skill), then he doesn't just lose it when he loses the hammer. If Thor loses the ability to do something if he doesn't have the hammer, then it wasn't a power **of Thor** to begin with. Tony Stark does not have the power of flight, Superman does. Arguably, the only power Tony Stark has is his engineering genius (which he uses to then create **tools** that help him). Spiderman's webs are a power in some of the movies/comics (=he creates them biologically), and sometimes not (=he builds the web shooters and web fluid).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty obvious that Thor can't do all the stuff that you mentioned simply because the hammer is not there anymore. However, he is still able to fly as we have seen in the movie. The "powers of the hammer" that Odin is referring to is, whatever things that Thor have done till now with the hammer, he will be able to do that without it.

Placing the hammer somewhere and Thor is the only one who can lift it doesn't considered as a power (even though it's pretty cool) it's mere a ability. The power that Odin mentions is  mainly about the physical ability the hammer posses and the ability to bring in the thunder. But as we have seen in the movie, Thor does't need the hammer to bring in the thunder, it was just a tool that was used to shape his power and controlling it.

Answer (score 6):

I think we need to differentiate between a few things here:

**The Powers of Asgardians**

- Great Strength
- Great Durability
- Long Life

These are innate to all Asgardians I believe (even if many are not as strong as Thor in particular). These also don't leave when Thor was without his hammer in Ragnarok, though they do seem diminished in the original Thor movie.

**The Powers of Thor**

- Fly
- Control Lightning

There are Thor's Godlike powers. He seemed to lose them without the hammer to focus them before, but those are actually powers innate to Thor and come from himself/the people of Asgard.

**The Abilities of Mjolnir**

- Unmovable weight unless lifted by someone worthy
- Ability to be controlled and summoned by Thor

I think these are traits imbued on the hammer itself, the weight one specifically as a test for Thor in the first Thor movie. They are not a power of Thor but instead a property of Mjolnir and Odin's magic. They are no longer usable with the hammer destroyed.